# How to make image_proc from source? Missing opencv2 dependency

Tags: ros, vision-opencv, opencv2, image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to install image_proc (non-catkin one) from source. However, its dependency opencv2 (electric version) deprecated. Does image_proc need opencv2 dependency anymore? Can I just delete opencv2 dependency from manifest.xml of image_proc?

This is the output of rosdep install image_proc:

```
root@linaro-alip:~/catkin_ws/src/image_pipeline-electric/image_proc# rosdep install image_proc
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
image_proc: Missing resource smclib
ROS path [0]=/root/ros_core_ws/install/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/root/catkin_ws/src
ROS path [2]=/root/ros_core_ws/install/share
ROS path [3]=/root/ros_core_ws/install/stacks
```

Thanks in advance!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55361/how-to-make-image_proc-from-source?-missing-opencv2-dependency/) by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 441 on 2013-02-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As of ROS Electric, OpenCV is used as a rosdep system dependency:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/opencv2#OpenCV_in_Electric

---

Originally posted by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) with karma: 1264 on 2013-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-02-16**:
I use gumstix Overo, I cannot use the cammand "rosdep install image_proc". I need to build from source. Do you know how to do that? Thanks!

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2013-02-16**:
I haven't used ROS with Gumstix yet so correct me if I'm wrong, but from what I read here you should be able to use rosdep (although it might take an eternity to compile things natively instead of cross-compiling): http://wiki.gumstix.org/index.php?title=ROS

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-02-17**:
Hi, georgebrindeiro, I updated the error that I got when I run command "rosdep install image_proc".